# How to get the Red Alert achievement in Yeah Bunny for Android?

Tags: achievements, yeah-bunny

In the game Yeah Bunny for Android, there is an achievement called Red Alert, which requires you to beat the first boss. But after I beat the first boss, I got the achievement for beating the third boss. I thought that if I beat the third boss, I would get the achievement for beating the first boss, but I didn't. I have now gotten all the achievements except Red Alert. I have tried replaying the stage where you beat the first boss, but I still didn't get the achievement. So, what should I do? Is that achievement just glitched?

Answer (score 1):

I want to preface that I am not familiar with the game. However, looking at the [Yeah Bunny! achievement](https://www.exophase.com/game/yeah-bunny-android/achievements/) percentage completed, it is falling in line with other glitched achievements in other games. One of the things that demonstrate this is that the complete third boss achievement has a higher completion than the first boss achievement even though in most games it is typically the first boss that is beaten first.

What I would recommend is to either contact the devs, on the dev's website [website](http://www.rgbdev.com/) he lists his email as contact@rgbdev.com. I would recommend starting there.